# Javascript Focus method fails to focus on list element

Tags: javascript, focus, element

I am trying to focus on the following element when the page loads.

```
   <li class="active"><a href="#settings-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="report-
    settings">Report Settings</a></li>
```

When I use the following script if fails to focus on the element, despite this same script working for all other elements.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#report-settings").focus();
     }); </script>
```

Comment: I added the "#" but it stil doesn't focus

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by focus? Do you mean to highlight it? If so, you need to add a CSS or inline style the element for that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to attach an event handler for the `focus` event on that element before you can trigger a `focus` event.

```
var $reportSettings = $('#report-settings');

$reportSettings.on('focus', function() {
  $(this).addClass('focused-class');
  console.log('I was focused!');
});

$reportSettings.focus(); //=> 'I was focused!'
```

Also when you `tab` to that element the callback will be triggered!